# PHP how can i remove substring between last slashes?

Tags: php, regex, string

Here is my string:

`test-e2e4/folder1/folder2/6.png`.

I want to remove the last part of it, so it should look like this:

`test-e2e4/folder1/folder2/`

How can i do that using `preg_replace()` ?

Comment: you don't need regex for this. PHP comes with functions like `dirname()` that make this kind of thing a no-brainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('#[^/]*$#', '', $string);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/GR1ZLVBQ)**.

Answer (score 2):

besides `preg_replace`, you can also use `dirname`

```
echo dirname("test-e2e4/folder1/folder2/6.png") . "/";
```